# Matplotlib adding distance between bars at certain points and adjusting xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hey I have this bar chart in matplotlib, where I want to add some whitespace between where the redlines are (not the red bars) and adjust the x-ticks so they are under each grouping of bars.

[image]

I have the following minimum example for what I have now in a jupyter notebook (though with fake datasets):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

set1 = [16.4, 9.5, 9.53, 9.57, 9.0]
set2 = [0.8, 1.90, 1.90, 1.90, 1.90]
set3 = [16.19, 2.86, 2.86, 2.86, 13.55]
set4 = [12721.93, 3.81, 3.81, 3.81, 3.81]

x = np.arange(5)

plt.bar(x+0.00, set1, color = 'b', hatch="/", width=0.25)
plt.bar(x+0.25, set2, color = 'r', hatch="\\", width=0.25)
plt.bar(x+0.50, set3, color = 'g', hatch="x", width=0.25)
plt.bar(x+0.75, set4, color = 'y', hatch="*", width=0.25)

plt.xticks(np.arange(5, step=1), ['Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3', 'Set4', 'Set5'])

plt.yscale('log',basey=10)
plt.tight_layout()
```

I am completely blank for ideas for how to actually do this with matplotlib, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust where the bars are placed and the widths of the bar by changing the first parameter (`x`) and the parameter `width` for `plt.bar`. Something like this should work:

```
plt.bar(x-0.3, set1, color = 'b', hatch="/", width=0.2)
plt.bar(x-0.1, set2, color = 'r', hatch="\\", width=0.2)
plt.bar(x+0.1, set3, color = 'g', hatch="x", width=0.2)
plt.bar(x+0.3, set4, color = 'y', hatch="*", width=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Had thought about the possibility of adding - to x